# What is the maximum size, read and write speed for micro SD cards on a Creality V4.2.2 board?

Tags: creality-ender-3, microsd, sd

What is the maximum read and write speed for micro SD cards that the Creality Ender 3 V2 board V4.2.2 can theoretically handle and what is the maximum SD card size in gigabytes?

Micro SD cards have several ratings such as V10, V30, V60 and V90 which is why I am asking in order to be able to select the fastest possible card.

Answer (score 3):

From what I have read and experienced, 16 GB is about as big as they can handle. Yes it can be partitioned down to 16 GB but if you are doing that then just get a 16 GB. I tried a 32GB in my Ender 3 with 4.2.2 and it would not read it.